# How to bold placeholder text in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using the i18n file in my project. I need to bold the text that goes in the placeholder of the property "missingItems". This is the property from the i18n:

```
missingItems = The items: {0} are missing!
```

controller:

```
var missingItemsArray= ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
var sMessage = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("missingItems", [missingItemsArray]);
            MessageBox.show(sMessage, {
                icon: MessageBox.Icon.WARNING,
                title: "exampleTitle",
                actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.OK],
                id: "messageBoxId2",
                defaultAction: sap.m.MessageBox.Action.OK,
                details: "exampleDetails"
            });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the component **FormattedText** like this:

I18n

```
missingItems = The items: <strong>{0}</strong> are missing!
```

Controller

```
var missingItemsArray= ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
var sMessage = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("missingItems", [missingItemsArray]);
var formattedText = new sap.m.FormattedText("FormattedText", {
    htmlText: sMessage
});
MessageBox.show(formattedText, {
    icon: MessageBox.Icon.WARNING,
    title: "exampleTitle",
    actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.OK],
    id: "messageBoxId2",
    defaultAction: sap.m.MessageBox.Action.OK,
    details: "exampleDetails"
});
```

Examples: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.FormattedText/code/C.controller.js

Answer (score 0):

```
font-weight: bold
```

add this to bold the placeholder text

Comment: Where exactly should i place it?

Comment: you can do this in your css or by javascript

Comment: But that is going to change the whole text. I want to bold only the {0} part of it.